Prove: If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are integrable, then $f_1\vee f_2$ is integrable over each $A\in\mathscr{A}$.
I need to prove the following result:

Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are integrable, then $f_1\vee f_2$ is integrable over each $A\in\mathscr{A}$.

Here is my attempt:

Proof$\quad$ Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are integrable, by Exercise 2.3.1 we have $f_1\vee f_2$ is integrable. Thus Proposition 2.3.8 implies $|f_1\vee f_2|$ is integrable. Since $|(f_1\vee f_2)\chi_A|\leq|f_1\vee f_2|$, Proposition 2.3.4 implies
$$
\int|(f_1\vee f_2)|d\mu \leq \int|f_1\vee f_2|d\mu <+\infty.
$$
Thus $|(f_1\vee f_2)\chi_A|$ is integrable and so is $(f_1\vee f_2)\chi_A$ (again by Proposition 2.3.8). So $f_1\vee f_2$ is integrable over any $A\in\mathscr{A}$.

Is this proof correct? Moreover is it necessary to prove it in such way? Thanks a lot for helping me check it out!

Definition and results in the question and my attempt:

Definition$\quad$ Let $f$ and $g$ be $[-\infty,+\infty]$-valued functions having a common domain $A$. The maximum and minimum of $f$ and $g$, written $f\vee g$ and $f \wedge g$, are the functions from $A$ to $[-\infty,+\infty]$ defined by
\begin{align*}
    (f \vee g)(x) = \max\{f(x),g(x)\}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
    (f \wedge g)(x) = \min\{f(x),g(x)\}.
\end{align*}
Equivalently, we can define $f \vee g$ by
\begin{equation*}
    (f \vee g)(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
        f(x) &\text{if $f(x)>g(x)$ and,}\\
        g(x) &\text{otherwise,}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
and $f \wedge g$ by
\begin{equation*}
    (f \wedge g)(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
        f(x) &\text{if $f(x)<g(x)$ and,}\\
        g(x) &\text{otherwise.}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}


Exercise 2.3.1$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ and $g$ belong to $\mathscr{L}^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{R})$. Then $f\vee g$ and $f\wedge g$ belong to $\mathscr{L}^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu,\mathbb{R})$.


Proposition 2.3.8$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ be a $[-\infty,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable function on $X$. Then $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable. If these functions are integrable, then $|\int fd\mu|\leq\int|f|d\mu$.


Proposition 2.3.4$\quad$ Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space, let $f$ and $g$ be $[0,+\infty]$-valued $\mathscr{A}$-measurable functions on $X$m and let $\alpha$ be a nonnegative real number. Then

$\int \alpha fd\mu = \alpha\int fd\mu$,
$\int(f+g)d\mu = \int fd\mu+\int gd\mu$, and
if $f(x)\leq g(x)$ holds at each $x$ in $X$, then $\int fd\mu \leq \int gd\mu$.



You might also want to check that $f_1\vee f_2$ and $(f_1\vee f_2)\chi_A$ are in fact measurable functions.

@user408858 You are right! That would be more rigorous. I think the measurability of $f_1\vee f_2$ (and $(f_1\vee f_2)\chi_A$) follows from the result in Exercise 2.3.1.

Yes, I agree. In Exercise 2.3.1 you should also prove that $f_1\vee f_2$ is measurable. Apart from that, you can prove that products of measurable functions are measurable, which yields measurability of $(f_1\vee f_2)\chi_A$.

Your proof looks correct to me.
Using Proposition 2.3.4 c) in each step, you find
$$\int |(f_1\vee f_2)\chi_A|d\mu\le \int| f_1\vee f_2|d\mu\le \int |f_1|+|f_2|d\mu$$
Using Proposition 2.3.4 b), it holds
$$\int |f_1|+|f_2|d\mu=\int |f_1|d\mu+\int |f_2|d\mu$$
Since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are integrable, you find with with Proposition 2.3.8 that
$$\int |f_1|d\mu+\int |f_2|d\mu<\infty$$
This yields
$$\int |(f_1\vee f_2)\chi_A|d\mu<\infty$$
